# What do lsblk major and minor represent?

Tags: filesystems

Experimenting with `mknod` and need to reference major and minor.

```
$ lsblk --all --noheadings --output "NAME,MAJ:MIN" --raw  /dev/loop0
loop0 7:1
loop0 259:0
loop0 259:1
```

Answer (score 1):

> The major number identifies the driver associated with the device.

```
8: SATA
259: Loop device
252: NVME
```

> The minor number is used only by the driver specified by the major number; other parts of the kernel don’t use it, and merely pass it along to the driver. It is common for a driver to control several devices (as shown in the listing); the minor number provides a way for the driver to differentiate among them.

Found in 5 seconds by Googling: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596000081/ch03s02.html

Comment: Nice that you found this in 5 seconds, but it does not answer the question with respect to `lsblk`. For example, it _seems_ that the minor is equivalent to the number of the partition, but is this really the case?

Comment: @PhilippLudwig thank you for the downvote, very appreciate it. No idea why you decided to find this answer and downvote it, must be a bad day. Here is your answer: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/block/partitions/core.c?h=v6.3#n365